# loop array and some indices have other array

Tags: php

How can I loop this type of array where only attribute name has another array? Thanks

```
     array(
        '0' => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => array(
                'firstname' => 'pat',
                'last' => 'lozan'
            )
        ),
        '1' => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => array(
                'firstname' => 'bob',
                'last' => 'brown'
            )
        ) 
    )
```

Comment: Do you want a way to read this specific kind of an array or any array where some elements are arrays and some are not?

Answer (score 1):

You can still just use foreach, nothing changes there..

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
  echo $item['name']['firstname'];
}
```